# Copy APK: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I have a ListView and a Context Menu that says "Copy." I wish that when I click on "Copy" is taken the APK and moved from data / app to storage / emulated / 0 / APK. I have this code.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            final long examId = info.id;
            ApplicationInfo app = applist.get((int) info.id);

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

 case COPY:
            {

                try{
                      File f1 = new File("/data/app"+app.packageName);
                      File f2 = new File("storage/emulated/0/APK");
                      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

                      //For Append the file.
                    //  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2,true);

                      //For Overwrite the file.
                      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

                      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                      int len;
                      while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                      out.write(buf, 0, len);
                      }
                      in.close();
                      out.close();
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                      catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                      catch(IOException e){
                      System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
                      }


            }

return true;

}
}
```

I get this toast when I click on Copy: 
/data/appcom.NameOfPackage.Package: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) in the specified directory.

How can I fix? I would that when I click on copy take the APK application and move it from /data /app to / storage/emulated/0/APK

Comment: shouldnt u be specifying **"/data/app/"** (extra slash at end) instead of "/data/app" ?

Comment: Yes, the slash is missing.  However, what you are trying to do may not be permitted on recent or future android versions.

Comment: Why not right? So to move the APK from one folder to another how should I do? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.getDataDirectory()` instead of `data/data/....` and use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `storage/emulated/0...`

Hope it helps

Comment: Normally this would be good advice, but what the poster is trying to do is abnormal, and this will not work there, as they want the directory containing the .apk file itself, not the storage associated with the apk.  However, what they want to do may well not work on later Android versions.

Comment: Chris, so how can I do to move the APK from /data/app/ folder to another?

Comment: What you want to do exaclty? copy Apk from any app installed on the device? or only the apk of your app?

Comment: Perhaps it is not clear what I want to do. I have a ListView with ALL applications installed on your phone, I would want that the click on an item of ListView extract (copy the apk in a folder, for example MyFolder) the apk of corrispettive application.

Comment: And where is exactly located the APK of every App??